# how to send a tcp acknowledgement within a specific time interval

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I am required to send a tcp acknowledgement to a message from a server within 2000ms, else the socket connection will be closed by the server. How do I ensure that I can send this acknowledgement before the socket closes?

Comment: TCP must do that, not your application.

Comment: The ACK is automatically sent with TCP at the ethernet interface and you do not need to set in code.

Comment: No. I am working with a client server architecture (request response model)  where I need to send an acknowledgement to ensure that I get updated data next time. But the server has a time limit after sending the response and I need to send the acknowledgement within that time to ensure that the next time i send a request, i get updated data as the response

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about an application-level ack -- this is outside the scope of the TCP-level ack that (as others have said) happens automatically. You'll have to architect your server solution to ensure this happens; there's nothing you can do at the socket level that will guarantee that higher layers observe your real-time requirements.